# PHP link list: What's wrong with this script?

Tags: php, wordpress

The script below should be exluding items that are assigned to the "my-menu" category. However, they are still showing up. Can someone help me identify the logic flaw?

```
<?php 
global $post; 
$cat=get_cat_ID('my-menu'); 
$catHidden=get_cat_ID('hidden'); 
$count=0; 
$myposts2=get_posts(array('post__not_in'=>get_option('sticky_posts'),'cat'=>-$cat,'cat'=>-$catHidden,'showposts'=>5)); 
foreach($myposts2 as $post) : 
    $count++; 
    ?><li><a href="<?php 
    the_permalink(); 
    ?>"><?php 
    the_title(); 
    ?></a></li><?php 
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: What does happen in the get_post() function?

Comment: Do `the_permalink` and `the_title` functions print result or return it? Source of this functions will help

Comment: Why are there '-' signs before $cat and $catHidden?

Comment: Is this for Wordpress? I'm assuming from the get_cat_ID method.

Comment: @James - Yes, wordpress (sorry, should have stated that in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the codex:

> Multiple category IDs can be specified by separating the category IDs with commas

So you want:

```
$myposts2 = get_posts(
    array(
        'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
        'cat' => "-$cat,-$catHidden",
        'showposts' => 5
    )
);
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a ton Adam! I've selected your answer and tested it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`'cat'=>-$cat,'cat'=>-$catHidden,` looks wrong to me. Assigning multiple values to same variable?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can modify it like so to work:

change the snippet:

```
'cat'=>-$cat,'cat'=>-$catHidden,
```

to:

```
'category__not_in' => array( $cat, $catHidden ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Two guesses:

1. post__not_in looks wrong - should it be a double underscore?
2. Assuming this is wordpress, I can't see a 'post_not_in' parameter on the [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) page of the codex